# Json Deserialization failed on token ... and has left off in the middle of parsing a row

Tags: json

I am getting this exception when parsing JSON that was generated via `json.serialize(trigger.new)`:

```
System.JSONException: Json Deserialization failed on token 'a0Po000000B12345678' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row
```

Seems to fail on second record:

```
{
  "a0Po000000B87654321": {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "custom__c",
      "url": "/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/custom__c/a0Po000000B87654321"
    },
    "LastModifiedDate": "2016-05-08T05:16:13.000+0000",
    "Id": "a0Po000000B87654321",
    "Status__c": "Active"
  },
  "a0Po000000B12345678": {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "custom__c",
      "url": "/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/custom__c/a0Po000000B12345678"
    },
    "LastModifiedDate": "2016-05-08T05:16:13.000+0000",
    "Id": "a0Po000000B12345678",
    "Status__c": "Active"
  }
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: The JSON you have posted looks valid: can you post the deserialization code (i.e. is it just JSON.deserialize?). How many records are involved i.e. is it possible you are running our of heap space?

Comment: Just a simple JSON.deserialize, around 7 records.

Comment: Any reason found for this? I am getting the same error

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I think I've ended up doing some alternative design.