# REST to create multiple objects-JSON Deserializaton failed on token null

Tags: json, rest, post

I have been trying to create CurrencyType records from APEX and since that doesn't support DML, have been using the REST endpoint and POST method.
Everything work fine with single record but with multiple records, I am getting this error:

[
    {
        "message": "Json Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
    }
]

I don't see how the code worked for single object, if it really were an Invalid Field.

I have seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120985/json-deserialization-failed-on-token-and-has-left-off-in-the-middle-of-parsi) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144818/deserializing-an-account-throws-an-error) but have been unable to fix my issue.

Here is my code:

```
public static void syncCurrencyTypeTableMultiple(){
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');

    List<CurrencyType> currTypeList = new List<CurrencyType>();

    for(sanmgdpack__PST_Currency__c curr: [Select sanmgdpack__ISO_Code__c, sanmgdpack__Conversion_Rate__c, sanmgdpack__Decimal_Places__c FROM sanmgdpack__PST_Currency__c]) {
        CurrencyType currTypeObj = new CurrencyType(
                                            IsoCode = curr.sanmgdpack__ISO_Code__c, 
                                            ConversionRate = curr.sanmgdpack__Conversion_Rate__c, 
                                            DecimalPlaces = Integer.valueOf(curr.sanmgdpack__Decimal_Places__c)
                                            );
        currTypeList.add(currTypeObj);
    }

    String jsonStr = JSON.serializePretty(currTypeList);
    System.debug('json Str:' + jsonStr);


    //test
    //List<CurrencyType> deserList = (List<CurrencyType>)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, List<CurrencyType>.class);

    //System.debug('deserlist::::' + deserList); //works fine

    req.setBody(jsonStr);
    System.debug(req);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    System.debug(res);
}
```

Comment: Thinking that wrapper class was causing the problem, I removed it altogether. (edited my code - current code has no wrapper) Even then same issue persists. Please could someone help me? Is SFDC support for multiple object creation through REST having a bug?

Comment: you are trying to insert multiple CurrencyType records in a single REST call? If so, you need to use the [REST Composite Batch API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm) that has some limitations. There is an excellent discussion on options in this [blog post](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/01/)

Comment: thanks a lot, you can put it as an answer so that I can choose that!

Comment: glad this worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFDC REST API for Create-Update-Delete operations only work on single records. To address this, SFDC added a Composite Resource feature that allows:

- [inserting multiple unrelated objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm) (your use case)
- inserting a tree of objects (e.g. Account and its child Contacts)
- inserting an object, then using its values to insert/update another object

and more. See the [REST API documentation on Composite resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_composite_resources.htm)

For multiple `CurrencyType` (max 200)

https://***yourInstance***.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/composite/tree/CurrencyType/

with POST body:

```
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CurrencyType", "referenceId" : "ref11"},
    "IsoCode": "USD",
    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
    "ConversionRate": 1.3   
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CurrencyType", "referenceId" : "ref22"},
    "IsoCode": "CHF",
    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
    "ConversionRate": 1.5
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

The `referenceId` should be unique and are used to assist you in correlating the REST Response body to see which rows failed to insert.

There is a [superb discussion in Daniel Ballinger's blog](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/01/) on bulk updating from an API that is well worth reading

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot cropredy, your post directed me to the right direction.

I have managed to get it working using REST Composite Tree same as [this SF Doc example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)

Here are the request details:

**endpoint**: https://na73.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/composite/tree/CurrencyType/
**auth**: Bearer

JSON Body:

```
    {
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CurrencyType", "referenceId" : "ref11"},
    "IsoCode": "AFN",
    "DecimalPlaces": 6,
    "ConversionRate": 1.5   
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CurrencyType", "referenceId" : "ref22"},
    "IsoCode": "ALL",
    "DecimalPlaces": 6,
    "ConversionRate": 1.5
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CurrencyType", "referenceId" : "ref33"},
    "IsoCode": "AMD",
    "DecimalPlaces": 6,
    "ConversionRate": 1.5
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CurrencyType", "referenceId" : "ref44"},
    "IsoCode": "ANG",
    "DecimalPlaces": 6,
    "ConversionRate": 1.5
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and discovered it was a problem with my client.  I was producing JSON directly to a String, and giving the String to Jackson to produce JSON.  Jackson encodes it, with the result that you get invalid JSON: the quotes around the field names get escaped:

```
\"myField\" : 123
```

instead of

```
"myField" : 123
```